# Loading different JS for http and https

Tags: javascript, headers, https

I'm using a third party JS file. And they have both http and https version.
My site have some pages loading in https while most of pages are in http.

Now my question is could I do something in header.php so if my page is in https it will load the https version JS, otherwise load the http version?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

If you link to the JS file just using something like `//examplesite.com/js/jsfile.js` without the `http://` or `https://` the browser should automatically get the correct http or https version

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, in all web development, not just WordPress.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the site [is SSL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_ssl) when [enqueueing your JS files](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    if( is_ssl() ){
      # Running HTTPS
      wp_enqueue_script( 'https-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/https.js );
    }
    else{
      # Not HTTPS
      wp_enqueue_script( 'http-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/http.js );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```